# Navbar links to created pages in gatbysjs using the <Link> tag not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I am fairly new to gatsby-js. Following the tutorial and documentation i created links to other webpages within my project using the `link` tag provided. However, on clicking the link within the browser i get this error-message:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

Along with this block of code in the **/.cache/navigation.js:173 directory**

```
  170 | if (document.title) {
  171 |   pageName = document.title
  172 | }
> 173 | const pageHeadings = document
  174 |   .getElementById(`gatsby-focus-wrapper`)
  175 |   .getElementsByTagName(`h1`)
  176 | if (pageHeadings && pageHeadings.length) {
```

I dont know what i'm doing anything wrong as this is how i wrote out my links in the navbar component:

```
        <Link 
          to={WhoWeAre} 
          class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-red-600 hover:text-red-300 mr-4"
        >
          Who we are
        </Link>
```

Comment: Your `getElementById('gatsby-focus-wrapper')` is returning null. Are you sure there is a div on your page with this id?

Comment: @Jackson none of the components that i wrote are using such an id

Comment: Can you provide some more details to your problem like the complete flow you are following.

Comment: I copy over the bootstrap classes and html elements from php code:
`<div class="mt-20 relative min-h-screen overflow-hidden">`

Into my gatsby js code. Since i'm using jsx i only have to change a few things, like adding "/" to `img` tags and using the `Link` component for in-website links

But when i import `bootstrap` the styling in the classes doesnt register

Comment: I meet this bug also

Comment: Ditto. It seems Gatsby chops up the DOM quite a bit.

Comment: Related to these two issues: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21263 and https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21139

They say it's fixed in Gatsby 2.20 but I'm having trouble with it in that version as well